how to fill Jlables character by character in Java Swing?
I'm developing a Wordle game in Java using Swing. I have an on-screen keyboard and a text field (like in the screenshot), and I want to output the entered words from the text field into JLabels character by character (that is, I need to identify each JLable). Here's how I added JLable to the frame:
    final int FIELD_HEIGHT = 30;
    final int FIELD_WIDTH = 30;


    int letterR = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        int letterC = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            JLabel letter = new JLabel();
            letter.setBounds((int) ((frame.getWidth()/2 - 2.5 * (FIELD_WIDTH + 5)) + letterC),
                    panel.getHeight() + letterR + 30, FIELD_WIDTH, FIELD_HEIGHT);
            letter.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1,1,1,1,Color.BLACK));
            panel.add(letter);
            letterC += FIELD_WIDTH + 5;
        }
        letterR += FIELD_HEIGHT + 20;
    }

How can I make words from a TextBox appear character-by-character and line-by-line in JLables, 5 at a time? thanks for the help


letter.setText(field.getText().split("")[j]); should work

Unless you do acrobatics finding the references to your labels you will only be able to fill them right when you create them. The reference letter is a temporary variable only - forgotten as soon as execution of your loop ends.
If you want to fill the JLabels later on (I have a gut feeling this shall happen when the buttons are pressed or the text content of the input field changes) you will have to keep a list or array of references.
So from the lot of references you need to pick the right one, then execute something like
JLabel label = ...; // pick the right label
char toBeAdded = input.getText().charAt(index);
label.setText(label.getText() + toBeAdded);


I tried to do this with a 2d array using GridLayout and it updates only the bottom line of lables, that is very strange. I also need to implement this task in MVC pattern, so we need find a trick to handle lables from view to controller

Share the code. We cannot guess what you did.
