Problem with filling Jlables located in a two-dimensional array
I'm developing a Wordle game in Java using Swing and MVC pattern. I have an on-screen keyboard and a text field (like in the screenshot), and I want to output the entered words from the text field into JLabels character by character (that is, I need to identify each JLable). Here's how I added JLable to the frame:
// Controller

        JLabel[] worldColumns = new JLabel[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            JPanel panel = view.getEmptyLabelPannel();
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                worldColumns[j] = new JLabel();
                worldColumns[j].setOpaque(true);
                worldColumns[j].setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, Color.BLACK));
                panel.add(worldColumns[j]);
            }
            view.addPanel(panel, worldColumns, i);
        }
    }

In view module I made 2d array of Jlables:
// view

JLabel[][] panelRowLabelsList = new JLabel[5][5];

Also there is a function that should set the text on chosen label:
// view

    public void setLabelPanelText(String ch, int i, int j, Color color) {
        panelRowLabelsList[i][j].setText(ch);
        panelRowLabelsList[i][j].setForeground(color);
    }

Also there is a ActionListener that do stuff if ENTER button is pressed:
// controller (count = 0 by default)

    class EnterButtonListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if (count == 4) {System.out.println("END");}

            char[] input = view.getTextFieldText().toCharArray();
            if (input.length == 5) {
                for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
                    int i = count;
                    String ch = Character.toString(input[k]).toUpperCase();
                    view.setLabelPanelText(ch, i, k, Color.BLACK);
                }
                count++;
                view.setTextFieldText("");
            }
        }
    }

When the function is triggered, only the very bottom line of Jlables always changes, and the rest do not change
Please tell me what could be the problem here.
The screenshot of program:


Don't post multiple questions on the same topic: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78348971/131872. All information should be kept in the same posting so everybody knows what has already been suggested.

Java Swing Wordle

I found a solution:
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            JLabel[] worldColumns = new JLabel[5];
            JPanel panel = view.getEmptyLabelPannel();
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                worldColumns[j] = new JLabel();
                worldColumns[j].setOpaque(true);
                worldColumns[j].setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, Color.BLACK));
                panel.add(worldColumns[j]);
            }
            view.addPanel(panel, worldColumns, i);
        }

We need to recreate worldColumns per each iteration
